# Update p:datalist when making a selection in a on button with primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces on springboot and I have a view xhtml

[image: like this]

And I want to update the datalist by value (diesel,essence..)

my view code is like this:

```
<h:form>
        <div id="left">
            <h3>Carburant</h3>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">

                <p:selectOneRadio value="#{carFormBean.car.carburant}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Diesel" itemValue="Diesel" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Essence" itemValue="Essence" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hybride" itemValue="Hybride" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="selectedCarsList" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </div>
        <div id="content" class="left_content">

            <p:dataList value="#{carBean.cars}" var="car" type="definition"
                id="selectedCarsList" paginator="true" rows="15">
                <f:facet name="header">
            Voiture liste
        </f:facet>
        #{car.id}, #{car.marque} , #{car.model.nom},#{car.carburant} ,#{car.immVoi}

    </p:dataList>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

and the table in my database is like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuyMs.png).

what should i add to code to make it work?

Comment: And the actual problem is? And always create a [mcve], see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: i want to update this datalist by value its clear

Comment: Add a valuechangelistener to the  bean triggered by the selectOneRadio that alters the cars list according to the new value.

Comment: thank you @Selaron , do you have please any exemple who explain that ?

Comment: @Selaron: Plain ajax should be enough. Valuechangelistener is less and less used since ajax is supported in jsf

Comment: @Kukeltje if there's access to the new/current value of the component from ajax listener, you are right -yes :) I just want to prevent OP writes a getCars() that does the filtering on each call - it should be triggered by a listener on-time. That was my implicit point.

Comment: @hadil you can increase your chances of getting an answer by showing an **actual attempt** in you question and ask for the problems observed. So far it reads like "please write the code for me".